# Problems in real DOS with mixed "goto" and "call" commands in a batch menu

Tags: batch-file, dos

I'm creating a batch menu in MS-DOS 6.22 and I need to use `if errorlevel` with mixed `goto` and `call` commands. I'm having some issues with the order because they are not executed as expected.
I can't start the other batch files without using `call` with the exception of `file6.bat` because I need to preserve environment variables.

This is an example of the menu:

```
:MENU
@echo off
echo [1] Choice 1
echo [2] Choice 2
echo [3] Choice 3
echo [4] Choice 4
echo [5] Choice 5
echo [6] Choice 6
echo [7] Choice 7
echo [8] Choice 8
echo [Y] Choice Y
echo [Z] Choice Z
choice /c12345678YZ /n /m "Select an option"

if errorlevel 10 call file7.bat
if errorlevel 9 file6.bat
if errorlevel 8 call file5.bat
if errorlevel 7 call file4.bat
if errorlevel 6 call file3.bat
if errorlevel 5 call file2.bat
if errorlevel 4 goto menu3
if errorlevel 3 goto menu2
if errorlevel 2 goto menu1
if errorlevel 1 call file1.bat
```

That's the behaviour:

- If I choose 1, it executes the 4th [`goto menu3`].
- If I choose 2, 3, 4, 5, Y and Z, it responds properly.
- If I choose 6, 7 and 8, nothing happens.

Could you please help me understand how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three facts are important here:

1. `COMMAND.COM` of MS-DOS 6.22 processes one line after the other from top to bottom of a batch file, except the command **GOTO** is used to continue batch file processing not on next line, but on line below the line with the label specified as parameter for command **GOTO**.
2. The DOS command processor **continues** processing of a batch file on another batch file without returning ever back to current batch file if the other batch file is specified on a command line without usage of command **CALL**.
3. The condition `if errorlevel X` means **IF ERRORLEVEL IS GREATER OR EQUAL 1**. It is necessary to use two conditions to check if exit code of a command or application is equal a specific number. The necessary syntax is: `if errorlevel X if not errorlevel X+1 command`. That is like **IF ERRORLEVEL IS EQUAL X** because of **ERRORLEVEL** must be **GREATER OR EQUAL X AND LESS THAN X+1**. These two conditions are only true **IF ERRORLEVEL IS EQUAL X**. Example: `if errorlevel 6 if not errorlevel 7 call file3.bat` results in calling `file3.bat` only **IF ERRORLEVEL IS EQUAL 6**.

Let us look together on the use cases defined by the key pressed by the user.

**Use case 1:** The user presses key <kbd>Z</kbd>.

1. `CHOICE.COM` exits with value `10` assigned to `ERRORLEVEL`.
2. The first condition `if errorlevel 10` is **true** and therefore batch file `file7.bat` is **called** by command processor.
3. `COMMAND.COM` continues on next **IF** condition line after finishing processing of `file7.bat`, except it contains the command **EXIT** which results in exiting the command process independent on the calling hierarchy on being really executed.
4. The second condition `if errorlevel 9` evaluates **not** the exit code of `CHOICE.COM`, but the exit code returned by batch file `file7.bat` to the main batch file. The exit code returned by `file7.bat` is most likely `0` and therefore this second condition and all other below are evaluating to **false**.

**Use case 2:** The user presses key <kbd>Y</kbd>.

1. `CHOICE.COM` exits with value `9` assigned to `ERRORLEVEL`.
2. The first condition `if errorlevel 10` is **false**.
3. The second condition `if errorlevel 9` is **true** resulting in execution of `file6.bat`. The command **CALL** is not used here. For that reason `COMMAND.COM` does not return back to main batch file after finishing processing of `file6.bat`. For that reason everything below `if errorlevel 9 file6.bat` does not matter on this condition being **true** because of batch file processing ends with finishing processing of `file6.bat`.

**Use case 3:** The user presses key <kbd>8</kbd>.

1. `CHOICE.COM` exits with value `8` assigned to `ERRORLEVEL`.
2. The first condition `if errorlevel 10` is **false**.
3. The second condition `if errorlevel 9` is **false**.
4. The third condition `if errorlevel 8` is **true** and therefore batch file `file5.bat` is **called** by command processor.
5. `COMMAND.COM` continues on next **IF** condition line after finishing processing of `file5.bat`, except it contains the command **EXIT** and which is also executed.
6. The fourth condition `if errorlevel 7` evaluates the exit code returned by batch file `file5.bat` to the main batch file which is most likely `0` and therefore this fourth condition and all other below are evaluating to **false**.

The behavior is more or less the same on user pressing key <kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd> or <kbd>5</kbd>.

**Use case 4:** The user presses key <kbd>4</kbd>.

1. `CHOICE.COM` exits with value `4` assigned to `ERRORLEVEL`.
2. The first six conditions evaluate all to **false**.
3. The seventh condition `if errorlevel 4` is **true** and therefore command **GOTO** is executed resulting in continuation of batch file processing on the line below the line with the label `menu3`. So the other **IF** conditions do not matter on this use case.

The behavior is more or less the same on user pressing key <kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd>.

**Use case 5:** The user presses key <kbd>1</kbd>.

1. `CHOICE.COM` exits with value `1` assigned to `ERRORLEVEL`.
2. The first nine conditions evaluate all to **false**.
3. The last condition `if errorlevel 9` is **true** and therefore batch file `file1.bat` is **called** by command processor.
4. `COMMAND.COM` continues on line after finishing processing of `file1.bat`, except the command **EXIT** is executed during processing of `file1.bat`.

There are at least three potential problems with this code:

1. The last exit code of an executed command or application of a **called** batch file determines the processing behavior in main batch file. That is not really wanted here.
2. If none of the commands in a **called** batch file modifies value of `ERRORLEVEL` like called batch file containing only a series of `set variable=value`, the next **IF** condition below the **IF** condition resulting in calling the other batch file is also **true** which results in calling one more batch file or continuation of batch file processing on code for `menu3`.
3. The code below the last condition `if errorlevel 1` determines what happens next on any other batch file **called** from within this main batch file in case of all those batch files exit with value `0`.

The third problem can be easily solved by writing next in main batch file after last condition `if errorlevel 1` either `goto MENU` to continue batch file processing at top with printing again the menu or `goto ENDBAT` with last line in main batch file being `:ENDBAT` to continue processing the batch file at end of the batch file which means finishing the processing of this batch file.

But it is necessary for the potential problems 1 and 2 to make sure that processing of main batch file continues not on next command line after calling other batch file, but for example with the menu.

```
@echo off
:MainMenu
cls
echo [1] Choice 1
echo [2] Choice 2
echo [3] Choice 3
echo [4] Choice 4
echo [5] Choice 5
echo [6] Choice 6
echo [7] Choice 7
echo [8] Choice 8
echo [Y] Choice Y
echo [Z] Choice Z
choice /C:12345678YZ /N /M "Select an option:"

if errorlevel 10 set BatFile=7
if errorlevel 9 if not errorlevel 10 file6.bat
if errorlevel 8 if not errorlevel 9 set BatFile=5
if errorlevel 7 if not errorlevel 8 set BatFile=4
if errorlevel 6 if not errorlevel 7 set BatFile=3
if errorlevel 5 if not errorlevel 6 set BatFile=2
if errorlevel 4 if not errorlevel 5 goto Menu3
if errorlevel 3 if not errorlevel 4 goto Menu2
if errorlevel 2 if not errorlevel 3 goto Menu1
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 set BatFile=1

call file%BatFile%.bat
set BatFile=
goto MainMenu

:Menu3
echo Here would be shown menu 3.
goto ENDBAT

:Menu2
echo Here would be shown menu 2.
goto ENDBAT

:Menu1
echo Here would be shown menu 1.
goto ENDBAT

:ENDBAT
```

The goal for every **called** batch file is to continue with showing again the main menu after finishing processing of called batch file. For that reason it is enough to define an environment variable like `BatFile` with the number of the batch file to call and make sure that always only one **IF** condition is **true** according to `errorlevel` set by `CHOICE.COM`.

The code above results in execution of `file6.bat` on user pressing key <kbd>Y</kbd> with ignoring the remaining lines in this main batch file. The batch file processing continues with pressing key <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>4</kbd> on appropriate code for the submenu 1, 2 or 3. But for the keys <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd> to <kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>7</kbd> is **called** the appropriate batch file, then defined environment variable `BatFile` is undefined and batch file processing continues with printing again the main menu and let the user take one more choice.

It is of course also possible to assign complete file name of the batch file to call to environment variable `BatFile` instead of just its number if the batch files to call have different file names and just file extension is the same for all batch files to call. In this case the command line with **CALL** would be `call %BatFile%.bat`.